# Remove tinting from iOS TabBar

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a TabBar at the bottom of my view that I dont want any tinting on. As od iOS 7, iOS automatically tints the icons blue and I dont want this to happen.

I have tried writing a custom renderer but setting the tint colour to clear simply removes the icon (should have seen that one coming).

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    TabBar.TintColor = UIKit.UIColor.Clear;
}
```

I want to have an image for the tab item without any tinting. How can this be done?

Comment: have you tried SelectedImageTintColor?

Comment: what you want does not make sense. No tint means blue tint, as you said, blue is the default. What do you mean by no tint? Applying a clear tint is applying a tint. If you do not want it blue, you should apply another color.

Comment: @SpaceDog I just want my image without any recolouring done by the OS

Comment: If the image has no color what color iOS should paint it?

Comment: @SpaceDog The image does have colour though. For arguments sake imagine it is an image captured from the camera (you get the idea)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot.

Tab bar buttons don't display colors. Tab bar buttons use only the alpha information from the images you assign to them. You can use a segmented control instead.

Answer (score 21):

If anyone still looking for solution, you can go to your image assets, select all your tab icons (including Selected style), and in its options choose `Render As: Original Image` instead of `Default`.

No additional action is required, you can select any tint color in your TabView (or Image View) but it will not affect it any way. Also you can do it programmatically, but this is bit more simpler.

Although I am not sure since which iOS this function is available, it might be helpful to others with similar issue.

[image]

Comment: I wanted my selected image to have original color and my unselected to have a gray default tint, so i used this method but also had a copy of each image that was default. Then in the storyboard i set the selected image as the one with render as original, and the unselected image to be the render as default

Answer (score 4):

A bit late but I had a similar problem, here's what I did. I created a custom tab bar and set the tab bar item to use the original image (without tint). Then, I specified to use the rendering template when the icon is selected.

```
public partial class UICustomTabBar : UITabBar
{
    public UICustomTabBar (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        //Set your colors
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.Red;

        foreach (UITabBarItem tabBarItem in Items)
        {
            tabBarItem.SelectedImage = tabBarItem.SelectedImage.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
            tabBarItem.Image = tabBarItem.Image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use original icons to show on tab bar and without using selected or unselected tint color which applies by default.

Then we have to use custom renderer for iOS and for Android we have to use vectors
For detailed information you check the below link

https://www.davidbritch.com/2020/11/display-svgs-as-tabbedpage-tab-icons-in.html

Comment: Please blockquote relevant passages from the link you shared to help users find information faster and prevent link rot.